# No whitespace between Seaborn barplot bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a Seaborn barplot using the code below (it comes from https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/top-50-matplotlib-visualizations-the-master-plots-python/)

I would like all the bars to stack up without whitespace, but have been unable to do so. If I add width it complains about multiple values for width in barh. This is probably as seaborn has its own algo to determine the width. Is there anyway around it?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Read data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/email_campaign_funnel.csv")

# Draw Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(13, 10), dpi=80)
group_col = 'Gender'
order_of_bars = df.Stage.unique()[::-1]
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(i/float(len(df[group_col].unique())-1)) for i in
          range(len(df[group_col].unique()))]

for c, group in zip(colors, df[group_col].unique()):
    sns.barplot(x='Users', y='Stage', data=df.loc[df[group_col]==group, :],
                order=order_of_bars, color=c, label=group)

# Decorations    
plt.xlabel("$Users$")
plt.ylabel("Stage of Purchase")
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)
plt.title("Population Pyramid of the Marketing Funnel", fontsize=22)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a matplotlib expert by any means, so there may be a better way to do this. Perhaps you can do something like the following, which is similar to the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542112/9245853):

```
# Draw Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 10), dpi=80)
...

for c, group in zip(colors, df[group_col].unique()):
    sns.barplot(x='Users', y='Stage', data=df.loc[df[group_col]==group, :],
                order=order_of_bars, color=c, label=group, ax=ax)

# Adjust height    
for patch in ax.patches:
    current_height = patch.get_height()
    patch.set_height(1)
    patch.set_y(patch.get_y() + current_height - 1)
```

[image]