# Sawtooth look in violin plot

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

From female/male counts in a `csv` file like below,

```
female,length
1,4
1,3
1,9
1,2
1,7
1,8
1,9
```

I generated the violin plot by using Python Seaborn. However, it has a sawtooth look. I do not have any prior experience in generating violin plots; however, there are examples on the web generating violin plots with the y-axis having integer samples. Can you identify the reason?

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20.0, 10.0)
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = "serif"
    
df = pd.read_csv('scores.csv')
df = df.loc[df.length < 15]
  
p = sns.violinplot(data=df,
                   x = 'female',
                   y = 'length')
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently, the lengths are discrete, so the plot has peaks at these discrete values

Comment: Make a histrogram / bar plot at the discrete values of length instead.

Comment: Are you using the latest seaborn version (0.11.1)? It has been adapted to cope more intuitively with discrete data. How many rows are there in your dataframe?  In older versions, you could try a different bandwidth, e.g. `ax = sns.violinplot(..., bw=.5)`

Comment: @JohanC playing with `bw` field solved it. Thank you.

Comment: @MaxNoe I will try that as well. Thanks.

Comment: > playing with bw field solved it. Thank you. 

I wouldn't do that, since you imply a continous quantity by that. You just smooth out the discrete values.

Comment: @MaxNoe, definetely right. I will go for histogram / bar plots instead.

Comment: You might also be interested in showing the data as a pyramid plot, e.g. [Population Pyramide with Python and Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619776/population-pyramide-with-python-and-seaborn)  or [No whitespace between Seaborn barplot bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59506982/no-whitespace-between-seaborn-barplot-bars)

Comment: Great suggestion, thank you @JohanC