# Removing white space between groups in barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I do have a plot and want to close the gaps between row group elements as indicated above:
[image]

I don't want to change the figsize since it hampers readability. Just need to adjust that white space to my liking. Fiddled with linewidth but no luck. Creating plots with this line:

```
ax = sns.barplot( y='config', x='value', hue='variable', 
         data=pd.melt(df2, ['config']), orient='h', linewidth=0)
```

Comment: How are you creating the plot? ````dataframe.plot.barh()```` ??

Comment: @Redox Added the code.

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888058/changing-width-of-bars-in-bar-chart-created-using-seaborn-factorplot) to be very helpful.